# Is irreducibility sufficient for uniqueness of invariant distribution for a Feller semigroup?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, ergodic-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Let $(T_t)$ be a strongly continuous semigroup of positive operators on $C(K)$, where $K$ is a compact space. Assume also that $T_t1 =1 $ for every $t\geq 0$.
(This is also called a Feller semigroup.)

Since $K$ is compact we know that there exists a probability measure $\mu$ on $K$
satisfying $\mu T^*_t    = \mu $ for every $t\geq 0$ (i.e. $\mu$ is invariant).

> My question is: to show that $\mu$ is the unique invariant probability distribution, is it sufficient to show that $(T_t)$ is irreducible?

Recall that a semigroup is by definition irreducible if the resolvent $R_\lambda=(\lambda-L)^{-1}$ ($L$ is the generator of $(T_t)$)
maps for sufficiently large $\lambda$ nonnegative nonzero functions into strictly positive functions.

I thought this should be true by applying some version of the Krein-Rutman theorem, but did not find a suitable reference.

The closest I found is Proposition 3.5. on p. 185 of this book ([link at Springer site](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-3-540-16454-8)), from which, if I understand well, I can just conclude that $\text{dim (ker } L) = 1$, but not $\text{dim (ker } L^*) = 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $K = \{0,1\}^{\mathbf{Z}^2}$ and take for $T_t$ the Glauber dynamic for the Ising model below the critical temperature. Then $T_t$ is Feller and irreducible, but it has two distinct ergodic invariant measures.

If however you know that $T_t$ is strong Feller (or asymptotically strong Feller) then irreducibility does imply uniqueness of the invariant measure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you add some references?

Comment: For the second statement, the references in this note: http://www.hairer.org/papers/InfiniteStochastic.pdf are useful.